# MySQL - order results by result of arithmetic/functional calls on two columns

Tags: mysql

I would like to return results based on the field 'score' and an arithmetic operation on 'time'. Here's what I would like to do:

```
select id, score from questions order by MIN(0, (10 - (time - 'now')/(60*60))) + score;
```

I am trying to order results based on score and based on some measure related to the number of hours that have passed since a row was logged. How can I do this?

Comment: You need to select the equation as an extra column, then you can sort on that column.

Comment: @ChipDean Thanks for your input. So do you mean I need to create that column with one query and then sort on it with another? Is there a way to do this in just one call to the db without a stored procedure?

Answer (score 0):

```
select id, score, MIN(0, (10 - (time - 'now')/(60*60))) + score AS sort
from questions order by sort;
```

This can get your sorted results without dealing with stored procedures, multiple queries, etc

```
select id, score FROM (select id, score, MIN(0, (10 - (time - 'now')/(60*60)))
+ score AS sort from questions order by sort ) AS t;
```

You can go a step further to eliminate the unneeded column in your final results.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, but this command triggers an error: 
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' (10 - (time - 'now')/(60*60))) + score AS sort
from questions order by sort' at line 1

Comment: select id, score, 10 - (time - NOW())/(60*60) + score AS sort
from questions order by sort;     Try this...maybe you don't need the MIN() function and NOW() instead of 'now'